# Dice Probability--Trying to understand the choose function

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

This is the Question:

Three dice are thrown. What is the probability the same number appears on exactly
two of the three dice?

I know three ways of answering this question (multiplication rule etc..), but I am trying to understand the following answer using the choose functions. Could someone please explain the different numbers used.

$Prob =  \dfrac{{6\choose1}{5\choose1}{3\choose2}}{6^3}$

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine laying the three dice out on the table in a row.

There are $\binom61$ ways to choose the number that will appear twice. Once it’s been chosen, there are $\binom51$ ways to choose the number that will appear only once. Finally, there are $\binom32$ ways to choose which two of the three dice will show the number that appears twice. Thus, there are $\binom61\binom51\binom32$ layouts that show the desired result.

Each of the three dice can in principle show any of $6$ faces, so $6^3$ different layouts are possible altogether. These layouts are all equally likely, so the probability of getting one of the desired ones is the number of desired ones divided by the total number, or

$$\frac{\binom61\binom51\binom32}{6^3}\;.$$

Comment: could you please offer me more problems (links) similar to this one where I can practice this principle? Thank you.

Comment: Also, does this principle have a name or is it just counting.

Comment: @user148834: I used three basic ideas here: $(1)$ the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}k$ is the number of ways to pick an unordered set of $k$ things from a set of $n$ things; $(2)$ multiplying the numbers of ways to make the various independent choices to get the total number of possibilities; and $(3)$ the fact that if the outcomes of an experiment are equally likely, the probability of success is simply the fraction of all possible outcomes that are successes. There’s no special name for this combination of ideas. \\ I don’t know of a good online source for similar problems, I’m afraid.